# Scrapy Crawling Speed is so Slow (6 pages / min)!

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and i build a project using `scrapy startproject zhanlang`.
but when i start the spider by `scrapy crawl zhanlang -o zhanlang.csv` ,it works so slowly!only 6pags/min! here are my code:

```
def after_login(self, response):
    #the site should log in,this function is TODO after login
    yield Request(url="https://movie.douban.com/subject/26363254/comments?start=0&limit=20&sort=new_score&status=P",  
                   meta={'cookiejar': response.meta['cookiejar']},  
                   callback=self.parse
                   )  


def parse(self,response):
    item = ZhanlangItem()
    for comment in response.xpath('//div[@class="comment-item"]'):
        item['name'] = comment.xpath('./div[@class="avatar"]/a/@title').extract_first()
        item['text'] = comment.xpath('./div[@class="comment"]/p/text()').extract()
        item['vote'] = comment.xpath('.//span[@class="votes"]/text()').extract_first()
        yield item
    next_page_url = response.xpath('//a[@class="next"]/@href').extract()[0]
    next_page_url = "https://movie.douban.com/subject/26363254/comments"+next_page_url
    if next_page_url is not None:
        print next_page_url
        yield Request(url=next_page_url,
                    meta={'cookiejar': response.meta['cookiejar']},  
                   callback=self.parse
                       )
```

here are my settings:

```
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 0.5
# The download delay setting will honor only one of:
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 16
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 16

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {  
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware':None,  
    'zhanlang.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware':400,  
}
```

my middlewares.py are:

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import requests, random, json

import base64

class RandomUserAgentMiddleware(object):
# random choice useragent
    def __init__(self, crawler):
        super(RandomUserAgentMiddleware, self).__init__()
        self.ua = UserAgent()
        self.ua_type = crawler.settings.get('RANDOM_UA_TYPE', 'random')
    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler)
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        def get_ua():
            return getattr(self.ua, self.ua_type)
        request.headers.setdefault('User-Agent', get_ua())
```

why it crawls so slowly? what should i do to increase the speed?thanks

Comment: You need to identify which part of your code is taking the longest (see [profiling](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/profile.html)). Is it downloading the webpage? Is it the `xpath` selection? (...etc).

Comment: From your code its seems no obvious issue. Run this on a AWS server or something where network speed is very good, instead on your home network. Some sites, starts delaying requests when they come from same IP, so that you can't bombard them with so many request. It may also be the case here

Comment: Do you have Autothrottle enabled?